how to fix harfbuzz external dependency in OS X 14.3 java 17 jpackage
The standard install of openjdk 17 on OS X using brew also installs the harfbuzz text shaping library because libfontmanager.dylib depends on it:
$ otool -L libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libfontmanager.dylib
libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libfontmanager.dylib:
    /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libfontmanager.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @loader_path/../../../../../../../../opt/harfbuzz/lib/libharfbuzz.0.dylib (compatibility version 60811.0.0, current version 60811.0.0)

This is "fine" for local execution but if a standalone dmg install is required, jpackage does not pick up the dependency and the dmg will fail to launch on a system with no java 17 installed.  In fact, harfbuzz itself depends on other libs that are not part of the standard java 17 install:
$ otool -L libharfbuzz.0.dylib 
...
    /opt/homebrew/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 27.0.0, current version 27.1.0)
    /opt/homebrew/opt/glib/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 7801.0.0, current version 7801.1.0)
    /opt/homebrew/opt/graphite2/lib/libgraphite2.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.2.1)
...

What is an appropriate workaround?  My application uses the javafx module and is a GUI.  Can I surgically remove the harfbuzz dependency if I am not doing any text shaping?

tl;dr: Perhaps using a different jdk will give you better results.
The required dependencies appear to vary by build of jdk, some don't dynamically link in harfbuzz like the openjdk build downloaded by homebrew.  Looking at different builds of java (one from eclipse temurian, another downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac) I get the following:
% otool -L .sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.8.1-tem/lib/libfontmanager.dylib 
.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.8.1-tem/lib/libfontmanager.dylib:
    @rpath/libfontmanager.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libfreetype.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libawt.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libjava.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libjvm.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
    @rpath/libawt_lwawt.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1463.2.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 904.4.0)

% otool -L Downloads/jdk-17.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libfontmanager.dylib 
Downloads/jdk-17.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libfontmanager.dylib:
    @rpath/libfontmanager.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libfreetype.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libawt.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libjava.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libjvm.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
    @rpath/libawt_lwawt.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1463.2.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 904.4.0)

